# How healthy is the LucidDB project?

Tags: database

I am working on a project that would greatly benefit from a column store database on the backend.  I was attracted to LucidDB since the feature set seems perfect, and I cannot commit to the cost of a commercial solution like Infobright or Vertica until the project has shown value.

The problem is, I am concerned about the health of the LucidDB project.  The internal wiki hasn't been updated in more than a month, and the website is full of broken links.  DynamoBI dying does not help the case.

Is there anyone who knows the state of the project, and how comfortable you'd be with production code relying on this database?

Comment: Might want to try MonetDB, it seems they are alive and kicking.  http://www.monetdb.org/

Answer (score 6):

LucidDB is no longer supported by DynamoBI as they are closing the shop.

http://www.nicholasgoodman.com/bt/blog/2012/10/08/dynamobi-is-dead/

Dr.Bharatheesh Jaysimha